# MS dos 6.22 supports dll library linking or not?

Tags: c, dos

I created one dll file from visual studio. I want to use in MS DOS 6.22 Os compiler. Actually I don't know , this version of DOS supports dll linking or not.

Comment: No, a "vanilla" DOS environment does not support dynamic linking

Comment: than it will support static library or not ?

Comment: Every DOS C compiler supported static linking, but you will not be able to compile a static library with a modern Visual Studio and use it in MS-DOS. They just use different architectures.

Comment: BTW, why do you want to target MSDOS? It is not really supported anymore, and won't handle most of modern hardware (e.g. x86-64 processors). Did you consider using some [Linux distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) instead?

Answer (score 4):

The executable files in DOS are .COM and .EXE. No DLL linking.

Comment: thanks !    than what about static library in same os.

Comment: You can compile static library (.LIB) but finally it will be part of EXE or COM file. You can simply share your functions as normal .C file.

Comment: than In which environment , I have to create the static library (.lib) which will run in DOS 6.22 .               and how to link .lib with my program in DOS.  please suggest me.

Comment: @sohitjain I used relatively long time Borland C++ 3.1 and it is very good IDE. I think Visual Studio 6 is able to compile for DOS. Latest version of Borland C++ is 5.02 and it supports DOS target.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic-link library (DLL) is Microsoft's implementation of the shared library concept in the Microsoft Windows and OS/2 operating systems.

The Drawing API, Graphics Device Interface (GDI), was implemented in a DLL called GDI.EXE, the user interface in USER.EXE. These extra layers on top of DOS had to be shared across all running Windows programs, not just to enable Windows to work in a machine with less than a megabyte of RAM, but to enable the programs to co-operate with each other. The code in GDI needed to translate drawing commands to operations on specific devices. 
On the display, it had to manipulate pixels in the frame buffer.